# Symfony dynamic wildcards in google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twig, symfony

I have a small application in Symfony3 with a google map showing some locations injected from the database.
What I am trying to achieve is to place a link to each location page inside the infoWindows of google maps.
The wildcard to the location pages is this :

```
location/{id}
```

So the `<a>` tag `href` should be the following :

```
<a href="{{ path('location', {'id': location.id }) }}">
```

This is the JSON with all the datas :

```
"[
    {"id":72,"name":"Stintino","lat":"40.94013320","lng":"8.223588900000"},
    {"id":73,"name":"Cagliari","lat":"39.22384110","lng":"9.121661300000"},    
    {"id":74,"name":"La maddalena","lat":"41.21655380","lng":"9.404712200000"},
    {"id":75,"name":"Sassari","lat":"40.72592690","lng":"8.555682600000"},    
    {"id":76,"name":"Oristano","lat":"39.90618200","lng":"8.588386300000"},    
    {"id":77,"name":"Spiaggia-del-oetto","lat":"39.20861110","lng":"9.169166700000"}
]"
```

And my javascript code inside the twig template :

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
{% block javascripts%}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     


    var locations = JSON.parse('{{ locations | raw }}');
    console.log(locations);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('wsMap'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0562194, 7.8577928),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: true,
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['lng']),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i]['name']
        });
        var idloc = locations[i]['id'];
        var contentString = Routing.generate("location", { id: idloc });
        var url = '<a href="'+contentString+'">link</a>';
        alert(url);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(url);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

</script>
{% endblock %}
<div id="wsMap" style="width: 100%; height:800px"></div>

{% endblock %}
```

Do you know how I can concatenate all the string plus the variable to render correctly the link inside the infoWindows ?

**EDIT**

After adding the FOSJsRoutingBundle and the routing.generate function I get only the last route generated in all infowindow of the map. But on the alert window I get all the routes ! (see code edited above ).
My javascript skills are very poor unfortunately...

Comment: Is that Javascript located in a Twig file within `<script>` tags?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yes it is , sorry I forget to mention it. I m gonna edit the script.

Comment: Do you realize that your JSON does not have an `id` value defined; so this: `var id = locations[i]['id'];` would not work. Is that your entire JSON, or maybe you missed something? You are very close...

Comment: @AlvinBunk my bad again...I forgot to post the updated output !

Comment: You cannot do it this way. Javascript is executed on client side, so that loop is not executed during rendering the template and `id` is not accessible.

Comment: @malcolm after some research I am using the FOSJsRoutingBundle in order to expose the symfony route to javascript , actually it works but it only shows me the last route on all the infowindows of the map, but if I alert the url variable I get all the routes properly formatted ! I edited the code in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the issue, I m using the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html) to expose the symfony routes to javascript and    basically I had to add the variable **url** to the javascript listener function.
So this is the working code for me :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
{% block javascripts%}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     


    var locations = JSON.parse('{{ locations | raw }}');
    console.log(locations);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('wsMap'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0562194, 7.8577928),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: true,
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['lng']),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i]['name']
        });
        var idloc = locations[i]['id'];
        var contentString = Routing.generate("location", { id: idloc });
        var url = '<a href="'+contentString+'">'+ locations[i]['name'] +'</a>';
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, url) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(url);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i, url));
    }

</script>
{% endblock %}
<div id="wsMap" style="width: 100%; height:800px"></div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the rest of your code looks good Salv Ric. You just need to use the `~` tilde for concatenation in Twig. I think it's just this one line:

```
var contentString = '<a href="{{path ("location", {"id": '
                      ~ id ~ ' }) }}">' ~ locations[i]['name'] ~ '</a>';
```

Can you try it and see the results?
I put in carriage returns, and they are ok after enclosing your quotes and use a tilde on the next line.

Comment: Have you already verified your Javascript first? For example, maybe hardcode everything in an html file first to verify just one JSON id entry works.